# Check embed's content if it is at the top of its own area

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe (in the middle of page) with auto scroll rule and I want to check if the scroll bar (of iframe) is at the top of its own area (not in viewport).

I'm not an expert in JQuery.. I tried to do something like this (changing the window to iframe) but with no luck.

```
$('iframe').scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $('iframe').scrollTop();
    // Do something
    if (scroll > 0) {
        $('body').addClass('small');
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('small');
    }
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you use the scrollTop property of the object?

Comment: @SamuilPetrov I updated my first post by adding my code.